# Node.js Tcp server EACCESS

Tags: javascript, node.js, tcp

Using net to create a TCP server on Node.js on a windows machine

```
var net = require('net');
var host = 'localhost';
var port = '7171';

net.createServer(function(socket) {
    console.log('CONNECTED - ' + socket.remoteAddress);
}).listen(host, port);
```

But Im getting this EACCES error even if I run the node console as admin with control shift click.

```
events.js:72
        throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
              ^
Error: listen EACCES
    at errnoException (net.js:904:11)
    at Server._listen2 (net.js:1023:19)
    at listen (net.js:1064:10)
    at Server.listen (net.js:1132:5)
    at Object.<anonymous> (E:\Xampp\htdocs\tibiajs\server.js:7:4)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
```

Since at windows I normally dont have to deal with these kind of privilegies issues I dont know what to do

Answer (score 0):

You have your params backward:

```
.listen(host, port);
```

should be

```
.listen(port, host);
```

Also I'd probably pass the port number as a number instead of a string, but either appears to work.

Answer (score 0):

Docs: http://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_server_listen_port_host_backlog_callback

server.listen() takes a port, with optional host. Signature is listen(port, [host], [backlog], [callback]). I think this is what you want:

```
var net = require('net');
var port = '7171';

net.createServer(function(socket) {
    console.log('CONNECTED - ' + socket.remoteAddress);
}).listen(port);
```